# What is this function in the Longstaff-Schwartz paper?

Tags: american-options

$F$ is the conditional expectation function (the "continuation value") and our approximate of this using $M$ basis functions is $F_M$... but in the paper, they have this theorem:

[image]

What is $F_X$? It has not been defined in the paper.

Answer (score 5):

From the arguments in the lines following the proposition [in this paper where the proposition is made](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ehjfurrer/teaching/LongstaffSchwartzAmericanOptionsLeastSquareMonteCarlo.pdf); it really looks as if  $F_X$ is a typo which should actually read $F_M$, which stands for an approximation of $F$ using the first $M$ basis functions. It is argued that:

> The key to this result is that the convergence
> of $F_M(w, t)$ to $F(w;t)$ is uniform on (0,m) when the indicated
> integrability conditions are met.

which clearly points to that the integrabilitiy condition in the proposition made for $F$ and $F_X$ really was meant for $F$ and $F_M$